# How to plot acc in image generator after training each batch?

Tags: keras, image-processing, deep-learning

I am using this code to run my model:
How I can plot the acc after each batch not after each epoch?

```
STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size
history=model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN, validation_data=valid_generator,
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID, epochs=10)

print("Total time: ", time.time() - start, "seconds")
with open(os.path.join("./results/Totaltime.txt"), 'w') as file:
    file.write('Total time = ' + str(time.time() - start) + '\n') 
file.close()


plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.title('model train vs validation accuracy')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('./results/TrainAcc.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.clf()
```

another question that I have is how image generator calculate acc for each epoch? For evaluating my model should I consider acc after each epoch?
My training acc after epoch 1 is 95%. Why this happens?